# Import LinkedIn data (profile information) to user profile in drupal

Tags: 7, users, social-network

I want to authenticate via LinkedIn and, after successful login, import basic user profile data into the Drupal user profile. We're currently looking into [LinkedIn Integration Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkedin).  Unfortunately this module doesn't have a strong support or new developments going. Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

That module is the only LinkedIn-specific module that does that; [LinkedIn Company API Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkedin_company) is for company (not individual) accounts and [flux LinkedIn API](https://www.drupal.org/project/fluxlinkedin) integrates with LinkedIn, but it does not provide any other functionality.

For quick Drupal profile creation, you're better off using one of the many social media login modules that supports LinkedIn (e.g. [HybridAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth), [Janrain](https://www.drupal.org/project/rpx), etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The [LinkedIn Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkedin) module provides integration with the [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/).

It bundles :

- a main module, that does nothing on its own, but provides a few
  functions other modules can build on.
- a [LinkedIn Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/node/919550) sub-module, that let users login to a
  Drupal site using their LinkedIn account.
- a [LinkedIn Profile](https://www.drupal.org/node/919598) sub-module, that let users display parts of
  their LinkedIn profile within their user page.
- a [LinkedIn Status](https://www.drupal.org/node/919550) sub-module, that lets users update their
  LinkedIn status when creating/updating nodes or comments.